# ajax parse xml response function wont recognize XML file URL

Tags: javascript, xml, url

im using the following code from another solution on here

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                url: "xmlfile.xml",
                success: function(xml){

                    $("#output").append($(xml).find("address"));

                }
            });
        });
    </script>`
```

and if i use the local xmlfile.xml file it works fine, but when i try to run the same function with the xml file hosted elsewhere, it stops working:
http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetUpdatedPropertyDetails.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz1ebcem1ra4r_10irx&zpid=48749425

I tried encoding the URL using `escape()` and `encodeURIComponent()`
neither of those worked.

what am i doing wrong? why does the function work with a local xml file but breaks when i use the other URL?

Comment: Because: Same Origin Policy.

Comment: so, how do i get around this?

Comment: You don’t, unless the remote site enables CORS.

Comment: then how do people use Zillow's xml output to display property information in their web applications? i dont get it.

Comment: Probably by requesting it server-side instead of client-side.